Selenium, no consigo hacer click en el botón de una ventana emergente
estoy utilizando selenium y me ha saltado una ventana emergente. Esta tiene un botón de 'Volver a buscar', pero por más que lo intento no consigo hacer click en él. El elemento del botón es el siguiente:
<button type="button" class="Actionable-module__root___RYTfN Button-module__root___UMNA6 Button-module__root--variant-primary___kATay Button-module__root--size-medium___kzFwl Button-module__root--variant-primary-action___o8tE1 ErrorAlert-module__button___bC7te Actionable-module__root--wide-true___HrQ5-"(esto es añadido)><span class="Button-module__text___jmX-w"(esto es añadido)>Volver a buscar</span(esto es añadido)></button(esto es añadido)>

Este es mi codigo de selenium
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
volver_boton = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/ button[contains(text(), 'Volver a buscar')]"))) 
volver_boton.click() 


Hola buenas, puedes añadir el codigo para poder ayudarte no solo el html sino tambien la parte de selenium

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
volver_boton = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Volver a buscar')]")))
volver_boton .click()

Revisa si la ruta xpath es correcta y si el boton esta visible con if volver_boton.is_displayed():
Piensa que tu ruta xpath / button[contains(text(), 'Volver a buscar')] puede ser ambigua y haber otro boton en la pagina web, etc...
Con el navegador de tu preferencia puedes copiar directamente la ruta xpath dando inspeccionar en el elemento -> click derecho -> copiar xpath y prueba a usar esa
